# cannot click proper element within another element

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to get some row by its name and then click on an element within that element.
What I do is:

```
// searching for a row with the given name of the column content
WebElement row = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'John Smith']//ancestor::div[@class='row']"));

//clicking button within the row
Webelement button = row.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='Click']"))
```

It is not working that way, it always clicks the button in the first row in the table. P.S. The `WebElement row` itself is properly identified and it finds the correct row. Only when I want to search a button within desired row. Any suggestions on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access immediate child element of parent element you need to provide `.`

```
Webelement button = row.findElement(By.xpath(".//button[@class='Click']"))
```

Or you can use this

```
Webelement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[//div[contains(text(), 'John Smith']]/button[@class='Click']"))
```

Both should work.

Comment: thanks, I meant specifically searching for an element within another element, so your first solution (second one I was aware of). Thanks, it works. I wonder why the dot made so big difference?

Comment: @jacob1989 The '.' at the beginning means, that the current processing starts at the current node

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to find the button using **elem** not **row**.
Perhaps using row.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='Click']")) will fix your issue.

Comment: sorry, wrong copy-paste, I previously named it 'elem' but thought it is meaningless here so changed to row to give better picture. So this is not it unfortunately

Comment: That's what I thought.
Assuming you are using Java 8+, you could use Stream object like :

WebElement button = driver.findElements(By.className).stream().filter(e -> e.getText().contains("John Smith)).findFirst().get().findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='Click']"))

Comment: yes, this could solve the issue but I've seen the above way as suggested online by others and also in other places in my company repo and it worked fine. I wonder what can I check to find out why this one is failing?